# Multiboot USB Kali Installation CD-ROM Mount Error

Tags: linux, usb, mount

I have installed 6 OS in my USB drive with **YUMI**.
I boot from USB, can run Kali Linux **Live**, but **can't install**.
I'm getting `Can't mount and detect CD-ROM drives.` error.
Unplug & plugging USB gives error, files not valid; because Kali files are in **/multiboot/kali-linux-2016.2-amd64** folder
I tried;

```
mkdir /media/usb
mount /dev/sba1 /media/usb
mount --bind /media/usb/multiboot/kali-linux-2016.2-amd64 /cdrom
mount --bind /media/usb/multiboot/kali-linux-2016.2-amd64 /dev/cdrom
```

but still getting `Can't mount and detect CD-ROM drives.`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with YUMI, but I managed to get it to work really easy. I read a post using a different USB installer that didn't support multi-boot, and modified it just a little to bind to the directory of the Kali boot folder and it worked.

It's very simple:

```
mkdir /media/usb
mount -t vfat /dev/sba1 /media/usb
mount --bind /media/usb/multiboot/kali-linux-2016.2-amd64 /cdrom
```

and that's it.